# How to integrate TestRail with Jest tests?

Tags: testing, jenkins, jestjs, testrail

I'm running Jest integration tests on Jenkins and I want to integrate them with TestRail in order to automatically put test results to TestRail. In this way I will know easily how many tests are passed/failed?

Does anyone tried that?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: No, I did not find a good solution

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this one https://github.com/zeljkosimic95/Jest-2-Testrail . Although your question is too old but it might help someone else. This is not official plugin but it may help you.

Adding a suggestion here, we should choose the tool after analyzing all the requirements in your software testing services and product. Because there is no official plugin for this except this https://gitlab.com/craydent/jest-testrail (haven't tried). But you still can do this without plugin with this library/code https://github.com/zeljkosimic95/Jest-2-Testrail

Answer (score 0):

You can probably have a look at [Agiletestware Pangolin](https://www.agiletestware.com/pangolin) solution which allows you to export results of your tests into TestRail automatically from popular CI systems.

In order to be able to upload test results, Pangolin requires you to create report in JUnit format which can be done by using https://github.com/jest-community/jest-junit

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of Agiletestware Pangolin

Answer (score 0):

The approach we have found to work well on our CI/CD pipelines is to:

- Use [the Jest JUnit reporter](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-junit) to convert Jest test results into a JUnit XML results file.
- Upload the XML results file to Testrail using the API, or even better, the [Test Rail CLI](https://github.com/gurock/trcli), which is a Python package.

For help on using the CLI with Jenkins, look at the [official docs](https://support.gurock.com/hc/en-us/articles/8045541772820-Integrating-with-Jenkins).